# How can I incorporate a foreign key into a django form?

Tags: python, django, forms, model

Is there a way that a foreign key can be incorporated into Django forms, or widgets into Django models?

I'm using Django 2.2.2 and I have a model created (Accelerator). I have also created a form (Review). I have created Review using Django forms because I need to use widgets to ensure certain fields display as radio buttons, and I understand that widgets can't be used in models.

However, I also need one of my Review form fields to be a foreign key linking to the Accelerator model, but my terminal has just informed me that this is an attribute that Django forms doesn't have.

How can I create a model or form which can make use of both widgets and foreign keys? Ultimately, I need for my Accelerators model to inherit a value from my Review form, probably by way of another foreign key.

```
class Accelerator(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    summary = models.TextField()
    overall_rating = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=3)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='admin')
    logo = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='logos')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

RATINGS = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']

class Review(forms.Form):
    subject = forms.ForeignKey(Accelerator, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False)
    author = forms.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False)
    feedback = forms.TextField(blank=False)
    date_posted = forms.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    mentorship = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(choices=RATINGS))
    hiring = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(choices=RATINGS))
    community = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(choices=RATINGS))
    fundraising = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(choices=RATINGS))
    corporate_dev = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(choices=RATINGS))
```

Comment: This is all kinds of confused. If you want to store the data for Review, it needs to be a model. You can use a ModelForm to create a form based on the Review model; then you can override the widget for the relevant field to be a RadioSelect.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ModelChoiceField`

```
field = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=YourModel.objects.all())
```

In your case,

```
subject = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Accelerator.objects.all())
author = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all())
```